# Grouping and summing, using non-aggregate critera to determine field selection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

[T-SQL on MS SQL Server 2005]

I am trying to group rows from a SQL table, but have a requirement on how to select some column options, not just based on the usual aggregate functions. So *e.g.* I have this table:

```
HeaderID    mold_no     pipe_no cp_date         class total_pcs total_pss run_time
----------- ----------- ------- --------------- ----- --------- --------- ---------
113149      1603        A22     2019-10-17      35    216       1         9.08
113320      1603        A22     2019-10-17      35    1         0         0.00
```

And I want to group by `mold_no`, `pipe_no`, `cp_date` and `class`.

However, I want to use the `HeaderID` value which corresponds to the greatest value of `run_time`.

So right now I have

```
select MIN(HeaderID) HeaderID, MAX(mold_no) mold_no, MAX(pipe_no) pipe_no, MAX(cp_date) cp_date,
    MAX(machine) machine, MAX(class) class, SUM(total_pcs) total_pcs, SUM(total_pss) total_pss 
from MyTable
group by cp_date, machine, mold_no, pipe_no, class
```

but of course that won't really work, as I can't guarantee the lowest-numbered `HeaderID` value will always be the correct one.

How can I select the desired `HeaderID` value based on the largest `run_time` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `CTE`, computing `ROW_NUMBER()` over the `run_time` values descending, doing the aggregates with window functions and then selecting the row with `ROW_NUMBER() = 1` (since that will have the maximum `run_time` value):

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT HeaderID, mold_no, pipe_no, cp_date, class,
          SUM(total_pcs) OVER (PARTITION BY mold_no, pipe_no, cp_date, class) AS total_pcs,
          SUM(total_pss) OVER (PARTITION BY mold_no, pipe_no, cp_date, class) AS total_pss,
          run_time,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mold_no, pipe_no, cp_date, class ORDER BY run_time DESC) AS rn
    FROM data
)
SELECT HeaderID, mold_no, pipe_no, cp_date, class, total_pcs, total_pss, run_time
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Output:

```
HeaderID    mold_no     pipe_no     cp_date     class   total_pcs   total_pss   run_time
113149      1603        A22         2019-10-17  35      217         1           9.08
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/db93ac/1)

Answer (score 1):

This is not aggregation; this is filtering.  Use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.run_time = (select max(t2.run_time)
                    from t t2
                    where t2.mold_no = t.mold_no and
                          t2.pipe_no = t.pipe_no and
                          t2.cp_date = t.cp_date and
                          t2.class = t.class
                  );
```